# How can I fix the 'Request URL is empty' error when making an API call to Bill.com with Postman?

Tags: api, postman, erp

I have very limited experience with API and Postman and I am trying to use postman to make an API call to Bill.com but I'm getting an error saying "Request URL is empty". My previous experience with postman is working with Intacct which has created and bundled collections already set up so I have no idea what this error means or how to fix it.

Bill.com developer site has an API tool that you can use to send requests, but I need to pass a request that the site will not allow, so I have to do it in something like Postman. I copied the request from the bill.com site and posted it into a new file in Postman, but I get that error. Below is the code. If anyone can help I would be so grateful. My boss expects me to know how to do this and I would really like to not go back empty handed.

curl --request POST 
--url https://api-sandbox.bill.com/api/v2/Crud/Update/Vendor.json 
--header 'accept: application/json' 
--header 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 
--data 'data={"obj":{"entity":"Vendor","id":"00901LGSXALTUNTLbuqs","name":"Test","track1099":true,"sendNotifications":true,"externalBillPayIn12m":0,"since":0,"payDaysBefore":0,"enabledCombinePayments":true,"sendInviteForPrivateVendor":true,"enableFundedInvite":true,"numberOfInvitesSent":0,"eligibleForEbills":true,"acknowledgedEbillBanner":true,"acknowledgedEbillError":true,"eBillEnablementFailed":true,"setupAutoPayPrompt":true}}' 
--data devKey=[REMOVED] 
--data '[REMOVED]'

I've basically just tried pasting this into a new api file and running it. I don't know where to start to address the error I'm getting.